# JWT authentication requires me to logout and to log back in to see updated information of a user

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt

I have a node.js/express application that's using JWT as authentication.

When my user logins it displaying their information using "user_id", I have an update method that will update that users information "first_name", "last_name" by getting that "user_id".

When I run my update method, the information gets updated but it requires my user to log out and log in to see the updated information.

Comment: You just described the normal flow of a system that uses JWT, but you forgot to mention what the **problem** is. Why are you using JWT in the first place? It looks like you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach can be one of those two:

1 - Do an update request and, if this succeeded, return the updated information in the response.

2 - Do an update request and, if this succeeded, after receive the 200 status code do a "getOne" request passing the user_id.

You need to replace the state of your frontend.

I don't know what you use on the frontend, but if were some javascript framework, the two-way databind will do replace for you.
If you use another tech such PHP, you need to refresh the page with the new information.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'm currently using vue.js in the frontend.